# Is dynamically writing to a csv file slower than appending to an array in Python?

Tags: python, csv, dynamic

I'm talking about time taken to dynamically write values to a csv file vs appending those same values to an array. Eventually, I will append that array to the csv file, but that's out of the scope of this question.

Comment: Why not test it yourself? If you're unsure how, show us what you've tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you mean to ask about separate calls to `writer.writerow()` vs. building a list, then writing that list with `writer.writerows()`.

Memory wise, the former is more efficient. That said, don't worry too much about speed here; writing to disk is your bottleneck, not how you build the data.